# Using 622x13c rim with 28mm tires?

Tags: road-bike, tire

I just recently bought a used Orbea road bike. The tires are currently iRC Jetty 700x23c on Omega ETRTO 622x13c rims.

is possible to change my tires to a bigger ones than the existing/ Possibly changing to 28c tires.

I am using the road bike to commute to work and cycle leisure on weekends but in my area there are lot of tram lines. Twice I got stuck in them, which is quite scary and dangerous. So I'm hoping this is possible, as I can't afford to get new rims too. Not at the moment.

Comment: Questions about tire width are very common on this site and there are plenty of existing answers. Clearance between the frame or fork and tires is likely be the limiting factor, not rim width.

Comment: https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html#width